# Amazon says I have a syntax error in this yml file, can anyone find it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml

I am building a rest api with lambda and dynamodb.

I am typing sls deploy in the terminal which should deploy my function to aws but it gives me a syntax error and does not say where the error is.

Another file is create using the yml file which aws uses but I am posting the yml file as it is easier to read.

This is the yml file. I have been tinkering with it to get the syntax right but it still is not working.

The exact error is:

An error occurred: IamRoleLambdaExecution - Syntax errors in policy. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: b089926b-6d47-4111-9710-e3b6987fd8d7).

I can post the other file instead if that would make it easier to solve. Can anyone find the flaw in this file?

```
service: sls

custom:
  settings:
    POSTS_TABLE: posts

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  environment: ${self:custom.settings}
  region: eu-west-2
  iamRoleStatements: 
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - dynamodb: DescribeTable
        - dynamodb: Scan
        - dynamodb: GetItem
        - dynamodb: PutItem
        - dynamodb: UpdateItem
        - dynamodb: DeleteItem
      Resource:
        - "arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:custom.settings.POSTS_TABLE}"

functions:
  createPost:
    handler: handler.createPost
    events:
    - http:
        path: /post
        method: post

resources: 
  Resources:
    PostsTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: "id"
          AttributeType: "S"
        KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: "id"
          KeyType: "HASH"
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:custom.settings.POSTS_TABLE}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Likely reason is that correct actions names **don't have spaces**. Thus, instead of

```
        - dynamodb: DescribeTable
        - dynamodb: Scan
        - dynamodb: GetItem
        - dynamodb: PutItem
        - dynamodb: UpdateItem
        - dynamodb: DeleteItem
```

it should be

```
        - dynamodb:DescribeTable
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
```